# Date validation issue for java program

Tags: java, date

I have been working on a program that tells if a date is valid in this format "mm/dd/yyyy"

But my program no matter what says every date is valid.
can someone help me and tell me where my problem is and if so explain whats wrong. Must relate to leap year. and must give a error message which i think i can figure out.

This is my code so please help me. I am a beginner so thank you for your criticism

```
 /**
 * Created by MacOSX on 9/18/2016.
 */
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ASS4ID1773 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    {

        System.out.println("Enter any date in ''mm/dd/yyyy'' format. ");
        String date = "";
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int mm = 00;
        int dd = 00;
        int yyyy = 0000;
        date = keyboard.nextLine();
        boolean LeapYear;
        mm = 0;
        dd = 0;
        yyyy = 0;
        LeapYear = false;
        if (yyyy % 4 == 0 && (!(yyyy % 100 == 0) || yyyy % 400 == 0)) {
            LeapYear = true;
        }

        /**
         * month restrictions.
         */
        if ((mm < 12) & (mm > 1)) {
            System.out.println("You have entered an invalid month. Please try entering a month that exists.");
        }

        /**
         * Day Restriction
         */
        if ((dd > 31 && dd < 1)) {
            System.out.println("You have entered an invalid day. Please try entering a day that exists.");
        }

        /**
         * Months with 31 days
         */
        if ((mm == 9 & mm == 4 & mm == 6 & mm == 11) & !(dd == 31)) {
            System.out.println("For the month you have entered, you have entered an incorrect day.");
        }

        /**
         * February month
         */
        if ((mm == 2 && !(dd < 29)) && LeapYear == false) {
            System.out.println("You have entered a day that does not exist in the month of February.");
        }

        /**
         * Leap Year for February but with incorrect day.
         */
        if ((mm == 2 & (dd < 30)) & LeapYear == true) {
            System.out.println("You have entered an invalid day for the month of February.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You have entered a valid date in the correct format.");
        }

        /**
         * Leap Year for February but with correct day.
         */
        if (LeapYear) {
            if ((mm == 2 & (dd == 29)) & LeapYear == true) {
                System.out.println(date + " is a valid date.");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(date + "is not valid month must have 29 days or less.");
        }
        if ((mm == 2) && (dd <= 28)) {
            System.out.println(date + "  is a valid date.");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You read in date as a string but don't do anything with it...

Comment: Okay so you got a string called `date`.  What are you doing to put those values in `mm`, `dd`, or `yyyy`?

Comment: Your `mm`, `dd` and `yyyy` are *always* zero; because that's all you set them to (twice).

Comment: you need to parse your input into your mm, yyyy and dd values cause they ramain 0 throughout the execution of your code

Comment: There are very many errors in your code.  But the first thing you need to fix is to set your `dd`, `mm`, `yyyy` variables to the actual numbers that are entered, rather than just to 0.  You may find it useful to use the `split` method of the `String` class and the `parseInt` method of the `Integer` class.

Comment: You code is not within the `main` method block. Please take a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

From my comment above: as your program currently is, you read in `date`, but you don't do anything with it.

Further, are you intentionally trying to manually parse the date? Would it not be sufficient to do something like

```
try {
    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
    Date date = df.parse(dateString);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // incorrect date
}
```

Edit (see comments section):

```
try {
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    Date date = df.parse(dateString);
} catch (...) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: @DavidWallace Well, in that case, you can use `SimpleDateFormat` and specify which format you want.

Comment: @DavidWallace ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ the question has very little information I answered based on what I was given.

Comment: In fact, this won't work in _any_ locale.  `getDateInstance` returns a _lenient_ date format, which means you can't use it to check whether a date is valid.  It'll only fail if the format is completely wrong.  It would allow things like 13/32/2016, where the format is correct but the numbers don't give an actual date.  So this doesn't do what the OP wants, and I have downvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

Your values never get set to the user input you asked for. You need to take the input from the user and then parse it into pieces that you can then call Integer.parseInt on to convert the String representation to an Integer.

Give this a try:

```
//check to see if the input recieved is ##/##/####
if(date.matches("\\d\\d/\\d\\d/\\d\\d\\d\\d"))
{
    //now split the string around / to get the 
    //numbers you need for your checks
    String[] pieces = date.split("/");
    mm = Integer.parseInt(pieces[0]);
    dd = Integer.parseInt(pieces[1]);
    yyyy = Integer.parseInt(pieces[2]);
    //now do your logic checks based on the numbers that the user typed

}
//the user did not enter the correct format of input
else
{
    System.out.println("Sorry Incorrect Input Format")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("/");

int mm = keyboard.nextInt();
int dd = keyboard.nextInt();
int yyyy = keyboard.nextInt();

// etc
```

Comment: I tried this.  It doesn't work.  My `Scanner` is still waiting for a `/` character to come after the year.  You need the delimiter to be _either_ `/` _or_ the end of a line.